# Is element visible in scrollable container

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, overflow

I am trying to make a fully style-able choice field for bootstrap. I am close to finished but I want to make the control handle up and down arrow keys properly. If you use the arrows to drive the selected item out of the visible portion of the menu I want it to scroll to the active item.

Most of the examples I can find of how to make something like this work only cares about being in the browser viewport. I need to check if an element is visible inside a different container element that has overflow set.

My current attempt causes the menu to scroll down before it's needed and never scrolls up to follow the active item.

I use jQuery in the site so you can use it in your answer or plain just plain javascript. Please do not reference any extra libraries, I want to keep this a light solution.

```
$.fn.visible = function(partial, parent){
    var $w              = parent ? $(parent): $(window);
    var $t              = $(this),
        viewTop         = $w.scrollTop(),
        viewBottom      = viewTop + $w.height(),
        _top            = $t.offset().top,
        _bottom         = _top + $t.height(),
        compareTop      = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
        compareBottom   = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;

    return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));
};
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Swazimodo/u9wo77aq/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to tell if a child element is visible in the scrollable parent. Here is the jQuery function that I came up with.

```
$.fn.visible = function(partial, parent, child){
    var $outer = $(parent);
    var $child = $(child);

    if(partial)
        return ($child.position().top >= 0 && $child.position().top < $outer.height());
    else
        return ($child.position().top - $child.height() >= 0 && $child.position().top + $child.height() < $outer.height());
};
```